# Hiding column in AG-Grid with linked charts makes charts show irrelevant data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I've on report page in my application where I show data in AG-Grid and show those data in charts.
For eg. I've Year, month, quarter, week columns in the grid and show individual charts showing cases by month, by week and so on. This chart and the grid are inter linked. So when I click particualar say week 1, then all the charts and grid will filter data showing only week 1 cases. You can see in the attached image.
The problem is, few of our client wants some of the columns to be hidden for their report export. But when they hide those column the charts get broken.
How can we achieve both inter linked charts as well as hide columns?
I cannot use `suppressColumnsToolPanel` as they want column to be hidden and I also cannot use unlink charts as data should filter among other charts as well as grid.

[image]

I tired `suppressColumnsToolPanel` but it will not work in my case. If I unlink the chart then it will not filter data on chart bar click